Constructing non conjugated cycles in infinite permutation group $Sym(\mathbb{N})$
In Dixon's book Permutation Groups, there is a question to give an example of two infinite cycles in $Sym(\mathbb{N})$ which are not conjugated. In order to build such an example I'm trying to figure out some things. If $g,\phi \in Sym(\mathbb{N})$ and $g$ is cycle:
$$
g = (\ldots a_{-1}a_0a_1\ldots)
$$
does the conjugation work as
$$
\phi^{-1} g \phi = (\ldots \phi(a_{-1})\phi(a_0)\phi(a_1)\ldots)?
$$

Reference for the exercise?

@DavidA.Craven, exercise 1.2.7.

The obvious way is to give them different sized  fixed point sets.

"Show that two permutations $x,y \in Sym(\Omega)$ are conjugated in $Sym(\Omega)$ if and only if they have the same number of cycles of each type (including 1-cycles). Give an example of two infinite cycles in $Sym(\mathbb{N})$ which are not conjugated"

As Derek says, you need to take into account the fixed points. All infinite cycles that move every point of $\mathbb N$ are conjugate, so the question is perhaps a little badly worded.

@DerekHolt, Does I understand correctly that cycles of the following type will be suitable: $(1)(2,3,4,5,6,\ldots)$ and $(1)(2)(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\ldots)$?

It seems to me that you got the idea. Anyway, I am uncomfortable with the notation $(1)(2,3,4,5,\ldots)$ simply because it doesn't tell me which natural (if any!!!!) maps to $2$.  I think the infinite cycles need to be bidirectionally infinite. In $Sym(\Bbb{Z})$ we have e.g. the infinite cycle
$$(\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots).$$
In $Sym(\Bbb{N})$ may be
$$(\ldots,6,4,2,0,1,3,5,7,\ldots).$$ Modify as required to get a mix of finite and infinite cycles.

@JyrkiLahtonen, may be I should write $(\ldots,6,4,2,1,3,5,7,\ldots)$ and $(\ldots,6,4,2,0,1,3,5,7, \ldots)$?

Yes. That would be my choice, too!
